# цикл for вложенный в другой цикл for

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Почему при выполнении в консоль выводит `011`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `i` не равна `011` - как было написано в первоначальной версии вопроса.

`System.out.print(i);` вызывается три раза и выводит три числа (цифры - 0, 1, 1) одно за другим, на той же самой строчке.

---

```
внешний цикл i = 0 
  внутренний цикл j = 0
    System.out.print(0);

внешний цикл i = 1
  внутренний цикл j = 0
    System.out.print(1);
  внутренний цикл j = 1
    System.out.print(1);
```

Comment: За 0, 1 я вот понял, а почему еще раз вызывает переменная i и равна 1. по условию то проходит i = 0, i = 1? и на 2 цикл прекращается

Comment: Внутренний цикл выводит значение внешней переменной i до тех пор, пока это количество не станет больше значения этой переменной внешнего цикла. При i = 0: выводим 0; При i = 1: выводим 1 (j <= i), потом 1 (все еще j <= i), а вот потом j становится > i и внутренний цикл прерывается. Переходим снова на внешний цикл, но и тут дошли до конца, т.к. условие (i < 2) уже не выполняется